# How does Github Desktop integrates with the Git commands (CLI)?

Tags: git, command-line-interface, desktop

So this is more a general questions, I am taking GitHub Desktop as an example.

Let's say we have a CLI software that does some stuff, just like git CLI:

```
git commit 
git add
etc
```

How the desktop version of GitHub integrates (if it does) with the CLI version of git to render answers and other information in the GUI?

The general question is: given a software X that works on the CLI, how one can build a GUI on top of this CLI software ?

Does Electron have some utilities to run cli command and parse the results, or somehow is it natively integrated with the C code of git ?

Comment: It's entirely possible it's just backed onto the [libgit2](https://libgit2.org/) library. If it's an `Electron` app, it could use this via `Node.js`.

But even if it does run git commands and parse their output, git provides a lot of low-level "plumbing" commands for just that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code here: https://github.com/desktop/desktop

E.g. `dugite`: https://github.com/desktop/dugite

which seems to be using the/a binary distribition of git: https://github.com/desktop/dugite/blob/main/docs/environment-variables.md#execution

Or more importantly: https://github.com/desktop/dugite/blob/main/docs/overview.md

`dugite` is a wrapper on top of the Git command line interface, with some helpers to make it easy to consume in your Node applications.